# How to get selected Data value to the route?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, drop-down-menu

Hello everyone I'm new to Stack overflow and posting for first time.
I' m making an attendance management system for School. In my registration and attendance table I have

```
Registration : class_id, section_id, user_id.

Attendance :  date, user_id, remarks.
```

I want the user to select the Class then Section and Date and then it shows the all Users of that class and Section through registration table.

I'm having problem in taking that selected data to the route. I have tried this I want the data from dropdowns to in this form

```
<a href="{{url('/registration/data/'.$classs->class_id .$classs->section_id)}}">
```

PHP PAGE

```
@php use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
$classs = DB::table("classses")->pluck("title","id");
$registrations= DB::table("registrations")->pluck("class_id","section_id");


@endphp



        <div class="form-group row">

            <label for="title" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Select Class:*</label>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-form-label">
                <select name="class_id" class="form-control" style="width:360px" id="class_id" required autofocus>
                    <option value="">--- Select Class ---</option>
                    @foreach ($classs as $key => $value)
                        <option  value="{{ $key}}">{{ $value }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="title" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Select Section:*</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-form-label">
                <select name="section_id" class="form-control" style="width:360px" required autofocus>
                    <option value="">--- Select Section --- </option >
                </select>
            </div>

        </div>



        <a href="{{url('/registration/data/'.$classs->class_id .$classs->section_id)}}">

            <div class="form-group " align="right">

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">

                {{ __('Submit') }}
            </button>

        </div>
        </a>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('select[name="class_id"]').on('change', function() {
                    var classID = $(this).val();
                    if(classID) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/myform/ajax/'+classID,
                            type: "GET",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success:function(data) {


                                $('select[name="section_id"]').empty();
                                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                                    $('select[name="section_id"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                                });

                            }
                        });
                    }else{
                        $('select[name="section_id"]').append('<option >No Section Found</option>');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>


    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Mainly having issues to get id of selected data from drop downs trying this:

```
   <a href="{{url('/registration/data/'.$classs->class_id .$classs->section_id)}}">

            <div class="form-group " align="right">

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">

                {{ __('Submit') }}
            </button>

        </div>
        </a>
```

want to transfer id in this form in routes

```
 Route::any('/registration/data/{class_id}/{section_id}','AttendanceController@getUsers');
```

Comment: Note: I have used AJAX so it only shows that sections which have up class selected

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just missing a slash in your url:

```
<a href="{{url('/registration/data/'.$classs->class_id .$classs->section_id)}}">
```

Should be:

```
<a href="{{url('/registration/data/'.$classs->class_id .'/' .$classs->section_id)}}">
```

Comment: Property [class_id] does not exist on this collection instance. Can you tell me what i'm missing

Comment: Your definition of the `$classs` variable/class does not have a `class_id` defined

Comment: What to do if I want the value of selection means the id that user selected and pass that value

Comment: Actually it is Class "Classs" and "Section" through which I'm getting values

Comment: You are also using a submit button without a form. This wont work. Do you want to store it like a form or with an ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

I think here you omit slash between class_id and section_id :

```
{{url('/registration/data/'.$classs->class_id .$classs->section_id)}}
```